# How to add a 2x2 mm hole to a SCAD file?

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design, openscad

I'm trying to modify this code to create a small 2 mm x 2 mm hole on the short side of the box (to fit 2 wires coming out of a battery):

```
// Which one would you like to see?
part = "both"; // [box:Box only, top: Top cover only, both: Box and top cover]

// Size of your printer's nozzle in mm
nozzle_size = 0.35;

// Number of walls the print should have
number_of_walls = 3; // [1:5]

// Tolerance (use 0.2 for FDM)
tolerance = 0.2; // [0.1:0.1:0.4]

// Interior dimension X in mm
interior_x=70;

// Interior dimension Y in mm
interior_y=21;

// Interior dimension Z in mm
interior_z=17;

// interior corner radius in mm
radius=0; // [0:20]

// What fraction of the flat X side should the hook take up? (0 for no hook)
x_hook_fraction = 0.5; // [0:0.1:1.0]

// What fraction of the flat Y side should the hook take up? (0 for no hook)
y_hook_fraction = 0.5; // [0:0.1:1.0]

// What fraction of the hooks should have a slot behind them? (0 for no slot)
slot_length = 0.7; // [0:0.1:1]

/* Hidden */
$fn=100;

wall_thickness=nozzle_size*number_of_walls;

// Outer dimensions
x = interior_x + 2 * wall_thickness;
y = interior_y + 2 * wall_thickness;
z = interior_z + 2 * wall_thickness;

hook_thickness = 3 * nozzle_size;

top_cover_wall_thickness = hook_thickness + wall_thickness;

y_hook_length = (y - 2 * radius) * y_hook_fraction;
x_hook_length = (x - 2 * radius) * x_hook_fraction;

module box_interior () {
    offset(r=radius) {
        square([interior_x-2*radius, interior_y-2*radius], center=true);
    }
}

module box_exterior () {
    offset(r=wall_thickness) {
        box_interior();
    }
}

module bottom_box () {
    difference(){
        // Solid box
        linear_extrude(z-wall_thickness){
            box_exterior();
        }
        
        // Hollow out
        translate([0,0,wall_thickness]) linear_extrude(z){
            box_interior();
        }
        left_slot();
        rotate([180,180,0]) left_slot(); // right slot
        front_slot();
        rotate([180,180,0]) front_slot(); // back slot
    }
    left_hook(); // left hook
    rotate([180,180,0]) left_hook(); // right hook
    front_hook(); // front hook
    rotate([180,180,0]) front_hook(); // back hook
}

module left_hook () {
    translate([(x-2*wall_thickness)/2,-y_hook_length/2,z-wall_thickness]) rotate([0,90,90]) {
        base_hook(y_hook_length);
    }
}

module front_hook () {
    translate([-x_hook_length/2,-y/2+wall_thickness,z-wall_thickness]) rotate([90,90,90]) {
        base_hook(x_hook_length);
    }
}

module base_hook (hook_length) {
    difference(){
        linear_extrude(hook_length){
            polygon(points=[[0,0],[2*hook_thickness,0],[hook_thickness,hook_thickness]]);
        }
        translate([hook_thickness, hook_thickness, 0]) rotate([45,0,0]) cube(2*hook_thickness, center=true);
        translate([hook_thickness, hook_thickness, hook_length]) rotate([45,0,0]) cube(2*hook_thickness, center=true);        
    }
}

module left_slot () {
    slot_length = y_hook_length*slot_length;
    epsilon=2; // ensure it definitely protrudes
    translate([x/2+epsilon,-slot_length/2,z]) rotate([0,90,90]) {
        cube([2*hook_thickness, wall_thickness+epsilon, slot_length]);
    }
}

module front_slot () {
    slot_length = x_hook_length*slot_length;
    epsilon=2; // ensure it definitely protrudes
    translate([-slot_length/2,-y/2-epsilon,z]) rotate([90,90,90]) {
        cube([2*hook_thickness, wall_thickness+epsilon, slot_length]);
    }
}

module right_groove () {
    translate([-tolerance/2+(x-2*wall_thickness)/2,-y_hook_length/2,wall_thickness+hook_thickness*2]) rotate([0,90,90]) linear_extrude(y_hook_length) {
        base_groove();
    }
}


module front_groove () {
    translate([-x_hook_length/2,-y/2+wall_thickness+tolerance/2,wall_thickness+hook_thickness*2]) rotate([90,90,90]) linear_extrude(x_hook_length){
        base_groove();
    }
}

module base_groove () {
    polygon(points=[[0,0],[0, -1], [2*hook_thickness, -1],[2*hook_thickness,0],[hook_thickness,hook_thickness]]);
}

module top_cover () {

    // Top face
    linear_extrude(wall_thickness) {
        box_exterior();
    }
    
    difference(){
        // Wall of top cover
        inset = wall_thickness + tolerance/2;
        linear_extrude(wall_thickness+hook_thickness*2){
            offset(r=-inset) {
                box_exterior();
            }
        }
        
        // Hollow out
        translate([0,0,wall_thickness]) linear_extrude(z){
            offset(r=-wall_thickness*2) {
                offset(r=-inset) {
                    box_exterior();
                }
            }
        }
        
        right_groove();
        rotate([180,180,0]) right_groove();
        front_groove();
        rotate([180,180,0])  front_groove();
    }
  

}

// left_hook();
print_part();

module print_part() {
    if (part == "box") {
        bottom_box();
    } else if (part == "top") {
        top_cover();
    } else if (part == "both") {
        both();
    } else {
        both();
    }
}

module both() {
    translate([0,-(y/2+wall_thickness),0]) bottom_box();
    translate([0,+(y/2+wall_thickness),0]) top_cover();
}
```

I've tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
// Adding a hole to the short side of the box
translate([interior_x / 2, interior_y - hole_size / 2, interior_z / 2])
    cube([hole_size, hole_size, interior_z], center=true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `difference()` function in OpenSCAD to subtract one or more 3D shapes from another. Source: [The documentation for the difference() function](https://www.openscad.info/index.php/2020/05/14/difference/).

For reference, your code already does that several times. Something like this:

```
module bottom_box () {
    difference(){
        // Existing code ...

        // Subtract the hole
        translate([hole_position_x, hole_position_y, hole_position_z])
            cube([hole_size, hole_depth, hole_size], center=true);
    }
    // Rest of the code ...
}
```

#### Two cube examples

Below are two examples of a cube with and without a hole (in the bottom) that, for testing, can be rendered in your browser on [openscad.cloud](https://openscad.cloud/openscad/):

##### 1. Model without a hole

```
cube_size = 20;
module simple_cube() {
    cube(cube_size);
}
simple_cube();
```

[image: model without a hole]

Example of [a model without a hole on openscad. cloud](https://openscad.cloud/openscad/?&sharedFileLink=W3sibmFtZSI6Im1haW4uc2NhZCIsInR4dCI6ImN1YmVfc2l6ZSA9IDIwO1xubW9kdWxlIHNpbXBsZV9jdWJlKCkge1xuICAgIGN1YmUoY3ViZV9zaXplKTtcbiAgICB9XG4gICAgc2ltcGxlX2N1YmUoKTsifV0=).

##### 2. Model with a hole

```
cube_size = 20;
hole_size = 2;
module cube_with_hole() {
    difference() {
        cube(cube_size);
        translate([cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2, 0])
        cube([hole_size, hole_size, cube_size], center=true);
    }
}
cube_with_hole();
```

[image: model with a hole]

Example of a [model with a hole in the bottom on openscad. cloud](https://openscad.cloud/openscad/?&sharedFileLink=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).

Comment: I've added this to bottom box but no hole appears. Not sure where it's messing up.

Comment: Are you sure all variables are correct and the positioning is correct? I would debug it step by step. First, make the shape appear solid in an obvious color, then position it correctly, and then try to incorporate it in the difference function.

Comment: @stormist The hole should be longer than the box. The hole should protrude the box on both sides ( translate may be needed to shift the hole ).

Comment: Modify this line: cube([hole_size, hole_size, cube_size], center=true); to this: cube([hole_size, hole_size, cube_size + hole_size], center=true); for a longer protruding hole.